# Can't get value of each json object in view django

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I using ajax to passing json array to view in django. But I can't get value of each json object. When I debug and displaed AttributeError object have no attribute 'label' and 'value'. Please help me with this problem. This is my code ajax and code in view:

```
var jsonArr = [];

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
        $('.form-group').each(function () {
            debugger;
            value = $(this).find("input[name='ValueRight']").val()
            label = $(this).find("input[name='LabelRight']").val()
            jsonArr.push({
                label: label,
                value: value
            })
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url 'add_label_value' %}',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                    'jsonText': jsonText
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        })
        console.log(jsonArr)

    })
view.py

def add_label_value(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        if request.is_ajax():
            order_header = OrderHeader()
                jsonText = json.loads(request.POST.get('jsonText'))
                for x in jsonText:
                    order_header.label = x.label
                    order_header.value = x.value
                    order_header.save()
    except OSError as e:
        error = messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, e, extra_tags='add_label_value')
        html = '<p>This is not ajax</p>'
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Can you show your django view method? I guess that problem is that the view is expecting fields ``label`` and ``value`` in data send by AJAX, but you are just sending fields ``csrfmiddlewaretoken`` and ``jsonText`` instead.

Comment: Add some printing or logging to your view. What is the value of `request.POST`, `request.POST.get('jsonText')` and `jsonText`?

Comment: Why are you catching `OSError`? I can't see anything that would raise that.

Comment: If i want recieved the json array i must use command request.POST.get('jsonText')

Answer (score 2):

Python is not Javascript, and there is a difference between a dictionary - which is what `json.loads` returns - and an object. You can't refer to dictionary keys with dot notation, you have to use string keys.

```
   order_header.label = x['label']
   order_header.value = x['value']
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

```
 import json

    def add_label_value(request):
        getjson = json.loads(request.body)
```